# Regex pattern for two letters followed by nine digits with bunch of stuff ending with \n

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am supposed to parse through a file which contains bunch of data includig gene IDs which are of interest to me.

In each line, there are multiple gene iDs and i want to get them all. 
they start with:

```
blah blah blah \trs397516819 A ---> V rs773801570 R ---> C rs730881000 I ---> T rs397516820 Q ---> E rs397516821 F ---> I\n

blah blah blah
```

so basically gene ID starts with "rs" followed by 9 digits then more gene IDs separated by space finally ending with "\n"

Example:

```
string = ['Gene_ID-Protein_ID\t\t3,4,15,20,23, rs397516819 A ---> V rs773801570 R ---> C rs730881000 I ---> T rs397516820 Q ---> E rs397516821 F ---> I\n']
```

parsing the above string should give the following result:

```
result = ["rs397516819 A ---> V","rs773801570 R ---> C", "rs730881000 I ---> T", "rs397516820 Q ---> E", "rs397516821 F ---> I"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{9}\b(?=.*\n)
```

As per your comment The updated answer would be:

```
\b([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{9}\s[A-Z]\s--->\s[A-Z])\b(?=.*\n)
```

1. \b stands for word boundary... which ensures that there is nothing
   but leading space/tab before the character class `[a-zA-Z]`
2. here `[a-zA-Z]{2}` indicates any two character. you may just replace
   with rs if you feel so then it will become `\brs\d{9}\b(?=.*\n)`
3. `\d{9}` ensures 9 following digits and the following \b ensures that
   nothing but but space or tab follows after this 9 digits
4. `(?=.*\n)` is a positive lookahead that ensures that it ends with
   newline

[Regex101Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iATrzw/7)

Sample Code:([Run here](http://ideone.com/PmSBoU))

```
import re
regex = r"\b([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{9}\s[A-Z]\s--->\s[A-Z])\b(?=.*\n)"

test_str = ("blah blah blah     rs397516819 A ---> V rs773801570 R ---> C rs730881000 I ---> T rs397516820 Q ---> E         rs397516821\n\n"
    "blah blah blah rs997516819 A ---> V rs773801570 R ---> C rs730881000 I ---> T rs397516820 Q ---> E rs397516821 F ---> I\n")

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print(matches)
```

Comment: can you also explain this?

Comment: @osaama.s explained

Comment: M. Tumam thank you so much for this! However, I do not want to isolate them like this. I also want the following R(or any capital letter) ---> C(or any capital letter)  for each gene ID. how would I do that? want to extract the following A ---> V too for each ID

Comment: plz give a bit of example input and expected output for clarity

Comment: it's a lil bitter different than the output you suggested but that's okay. I will modify it. thank you so much!

Comment: M. Tumam the modified code is not meeting the output format. it is only giving the numbers not "rs" and "A ---> V"

Comment: M. Tuman how would I change the regex pattern if I also wanted to look for  protein ID in each line line which starts with "NM_" followed by six digits then "-XP_" followed by 9 digits then "." and one more digit? example: NM_002880-XP_011532277.1

Answer (score 0):

With GNU grep you can use this:

```
grep -Eo 'rs[[:digit:]]{9}.*\n' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the gene ids, use a capture group with the following regex

```
rs\d{9} \w ---> \w
```